# Turn php foreach syntax to asp.net using telerik RadGrid

Tags: php, asp.net, telerik

I am writing code in ASP.NET and I am new at it. I have two arrays, one of names and the other of ids.

I want to create a table that would have the names in one column and two links which depend on the ids in the other column (edit to this specific name link, delete to this specific name link).

In PHP I would do it this way:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Title</td>
  <td>Actions</td>
 </tr>
 <?php 
  $names = Array("a", "b", "c");
  $ids = Array("1", "2", "3");
  for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++):
 ?>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <?php echo $names[$i]; ?>
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $ids[$i]; ?>">Edit</a>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $ids[$i]; ?>">Delete</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I understand that you can write something very similar in ASP.NET, but I have to use RadGrids. A huge thanks for help!

EDIT:
If it is important, I get the data as an XML, and I chose to parse it as 2 arrays. If it is easier, I can parse it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadGrids are an asp.net webforms control, you would normally bind the control to a datasource, and then change properties programatically in the code behind.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that out, but how do I bind data source that includes an array of names on one side and asp:hyperlinks on the other?

Comment: You can bind direclty to an array, but in your case you need to create a dataset and then bind to the dataset. There are loads of examples of doing this on the web, e.g http://vb.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-create-without-database.htm and esp at www.asp.net

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Title</td>
  <td>Actions</td>
 </tr>
<% string [] names = new string [] {"a", "b", "c"};
string [] ids = new string [] {"1", "2", "3"};
foreach (int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
{
%>
  <tr>
   <td>
<% names[i] %>
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="edit.php?id=<% ids[i] %>">Edit</a>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<% ids[i] %>">Delete</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: How to do the same thing using telerik:radgrid?

Comment: this is simple conversion of php to asp.net , telerik grid or even gridview directly not allow adding row like this , only html control allows this kind of dynamic row adding as they don't have to maintain view state.